# KendoWindow AngularJS: transcluded elements are not shown

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

The code below wraps a KendoWindow in a directive. The objective is twofold: (1) to open/close KendoWindow via $broadcast and **avoid** having window open/close methods in the controller (as these methods modify the DOM and not the model), and (2) use transclusion to define in the component child elements that will be shown in the KendoWindow and handled in the controller.

The problem is that the elements don't show up in the KendoWindow ([see plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/qrdr4hxsUCeOPI1Ksiwp?p=preview)) and the drow down list doesn't work. What's wrong with this code?

HTML:

```
  <button ng-click="open()">Open window</button>
  <button ng-click="close()">Close window</button>

  <div my-window title="'This is the title'">
      <p>Some HTML content</p>
      <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      <select kendo-drop-down-list="ddl" style="width: 200px" k-options="ddlOptions">
          <option>xxx</option>
          <option>yyy</option>
          <option>zzz</option>
      </select>
  </div>
```

Javascript:

```
 var app = angular.module("app", [ "kendo.directives" ]);

 function MyCtrl($scope) {

     $scope.open = function () {
         $scope.$broadcast('open');
     };


    $scope.close = function () {
         $scope.$broadcast('close');
    };


    $scope.ddlOptions =  {

      select: function() {
        alert('selected');
      }
    }; 
}

app.directive('myWindow', function() {

    var directive = {};

    directive.restrict = 'AE';

    directive.transclude = true;

    directive.scope = { title: '=' };

    directive.template = '<div kendo-window="win" k-width="500" k-visible="false" ng-transclude></div>';

    directive.link = function(scope, element, attrs) {


        var init = function() {
            scope.win.title(scope.title);
         };


        scope.$on("open", function(){
            scope.win.center();
            scope.win.open();
        });


       scope.$on("close", function(){
           scope.win.close();
       });


    scope.$on("kendoWidgetCreated", function(event, widget){

        if (widget === scope.win ) {
            init();
        }

    });


 };


 return directive;

});
```